# How to set global variables in gradle.kts?

Tags: android, gradle-kotlin-dsl

My app uses several gradle.kts scripts. I want to set one variable which would be global for everyone.

```
object Versions{
   val kotlin_version = "1.3.60-eap-25"
}
```

but it is not resolved:

```
 classpath ("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$Versions.kotlin_version")
```

Comment: Version class is not resolved or kotlin_version val?

Comment: Version class is not resolved

Comment: are you using curly brackets in your code?

Answer (score 9):

Declared them in `gradle.properties` file:

```
kotlin_version = 1.3.60-eap-25
```

And use it everywhere by `findProperty("kotlin_version ")`

Comment: Thank you, but this does not work in plugins {} block :(

Comment: If you want there as well, use an `object` in `buildSrc`

Answer (score 5):

in project level gradle
the

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.61'
```

Should just be:

```
val kotlinVersion by rootProject.extra { "1.3.61" }
```

And then you can access it by doing this:

```
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:${rootProject.extra.get("kotlinVersion")}")
```

in your app module

Answer (score 0):

To have your property available in *any* build section (including the `plugins`) you can map it as a [system property](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:gradle_system_properties) using the `systemProp` prefix in your `gradle.properties` file, like so:

```
systemProp.kotlinVersion = 1.9.0
```

and access it anywhere in your `build.gradle.kts` script(s), for example:

```kotlin
plugins {
    val kotlinVersion: String by System.getProperties()

    kotlin("android").version(kotlinVersion).apply(false)
}
```

For regular sections (e.g. `dependencies`) you may omit the `systemProp.` prefix and access the value specified in your `gradle.properties` (e.g. `myVersion = 1.2.3`) like so:

```kotlin
dependencies {
    val myVersion: String by project

    implementation("some.group:artifactId:$myVersion")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Migrate your build to version catalogs](https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-catalogs#kts)

> Start by creating a version catalog file. In your root project's gradle folder, create a file called libs.versions.toml. Gradle looks for the catalog in the libs.versions.toml file by default, so we recommend using this default name.

libs.versions.toml

```
[versions]
hilt = "2.50"
```

build.gradle.kts

```
implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:${libs.versions.hilt.get()}")
```

You can also specify plugins and libraries

libs.versions.toml

```
[versions]
hilt = "2.50"
kotlin = "1.9.22"

[plugins]
application = { id = "com.android.application", version = "8.2.2" }
jetbrains = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }
kapt = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt", version.ref = "kotlin" }
hilt = { id = "com.google.dagger.hilt.android", version.ref = "hilt" }

[libraries]
hilt-android = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-android", version.ref = "hilt" }
hilt-compiler = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler", version.ref = "hilt" }
```

build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains)
    alias(libs.plugins.kapt)
    alias(libs.plugins.hilt)
}

dependencies {
    implementation(libs.hilt.android)
    kapt(libs.hilt.compiler)
}
```

You can also combine multiple libraries into one via `[bundles]`
[Documents additional options for configuring your catalog file](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sub::toml-dependencies-format)